# pandas fails to compare Series with scalar

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare a pandas.Series with a scalar. For example:

```
pd.Series([1, 1, 1, np.nan, 1], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) <= 30
```

same as :

```
pd.Series([1, 1, 1, np.nan, 1], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']).le(30)
```

This fails with the error: "`{TypeError}expected 1 argument, got 2`" (This is a Python error, not pandas as far as I can tell)

The documentation for pandas.Series.le (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html#pandas-series-le) says that "other" (the argument) can be a scalar. So why doesn't this work ?

-> I would like to get a pandas.Series with bool values back.

Comment: pandas version 1.2.4. cannot replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your pandas. It's working on version 1.1.5